# Removing one number from line while keeping everything else same

Tags: regex, unix, sed, gnu

I have a file containing lines like

```
insert into table_name    (params1,params2,params3)  values (43044,'x',23547003);
insert into table_name    (params1,params2,params3)  values (43024,'y',26557003);
.....
```

I want to remove the first column/value pair. i.e. this is the desired output.

```
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values ('x',23547003); 
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values ('y',26557003);
```

How can I do this?

here is what I did till now

```
cat file_name | sed 's/params1,//g'
```

This removes the params1 but how do I remove the number after values?

Tl;dr

change from `insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values (43024,'y',26557003);` to `insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values ('y',26557003);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -e 's/params1,//' -e 's/values ([^,]*,/values (/'
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax> cat infile
insert into table_name    (params1,params2,params3)  values (43044,'x',23547003);
insert into table_name    (params1,params2,params3)  values (43024,'y',26557003);

pax> sed -e 's/params1,//' -e 's/values ([^,]*,/values (/' infile
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values (x,23547003);
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values (y,26557003);
```

The first `sed` argument you already have. The second simply finds the first string made up of:

- the string `"values ("`;
- zero or more non-comma characters (greedy match, as many as possible); and
- a comma.

Then it replaces that with `"values ("` which effectively gets rid of the first argument of the values.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks for the explanation as well. That is more important than giving the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `sed`. It finds an opening parenthesis then matches everything not a comma (`[^,]`) any number of times, followed by a comma. And replaces this match with an opening parenthesis:

```
sed 's/([^,]*,/(/g' file.txt
```

Results:

```
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values ('x',23547003);
insert into table_name    (params2,params3)  values ('y',26557003);
```

Answer (score 1):

The sed solution will only work if the first param is called params1. If it changes, you'll break... I recommend using awk instead. Awk groks these kind of things. You can split up your columns like so:

cat file | awk '{print $n}' (where n is the field number such as 1, 2 3, etc)

then you can sed if you wish, but i recommend you use this to split the comma delimited vals:

```
for i in `cat file`; do
  thing=echo $i
  old=$(echo $thing | awk '{print $4}') #This should get you (43044,'x',23547003)
  new=$(echo "\($(echo $old | cut -d \, -f 2)\,$(echo $old | cut -d \, -f 3)\)") 

  #then just replace old with new... 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

@paxdiablo's answer is entirely correct, but it runs a slight risk of modifying too much of your input file if any of the `insert` lines modify a table other than `table_name`.  If that happens to be the case, you might consider a small sed script like the following:

```
# fixup.sed
/^insert into table_name/{
    s/params1,//
    s/values ([^,]*,/values (/
}
```

In the above, the two `s///` commands are only executed on lines that start with `insert into table_name`.  Apply this script like this:

```
$ sed -f fixup.sed < input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed solutions are fine, but fairly fragile (consider the case where there is a newline between `values` and the next comma.)  Try `m4`:

```
m4 -D "table_name=\`table_name'( shift( \$* ))" \
   -D "values=\`values'( shift( \$* ))" input-file
```